# ValueError: could not convert string to float in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to find the average of each row in a CSV file as follows:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        scores = row
        average = sum([float(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
```

However, I'm always getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
'0.3183098861837984\t0.0021994616367169914\t0.0017398716418448568\t0.002779444153298143\t0.0044629274068791434\t0.0012644430669709003\t0.003083531279794444\t0.004509550881264837\t0.003608705125189259\t0.006833702582258458\t0.0018230394455706783\t0.001852023514636493\t0.004720184835956941\t0.006038977572546727\t0.004769535833937563\t0.0016622734203053761\t0.009311664834557762\t0.002327769746299017\t0.0020053588662354263\t0.006252191840044608\t0.006794853486350821\t0.007258945010249113\t0.00559368878955651\t0.002391455287537788\t0.002168369276873031'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It looks like you're treating multiple tab-delimited values asa  single value and trying to convert them all to a single float. Have you tried splitting the row on tab characters before trying to convert?

Comment: Specify separator. Looks like tab character \t

Comment: Does it solve your problem after adding `delimiter='\t'`?

Comment: Specifying the field separator is mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) in the documentation (and shown in many of the example code snippets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your `.csv` file is `tab` separated and not `,` separated
- use `delimiter='\t'` while reading the csv file. This should fix the problem.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        scores = row
        average = sum([float(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
```